# Java OutOfMemoryError in Corda 3

Tags: corda

When running a Corda 3 node, I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread “main” java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

How can I increase the amount of memory available to the node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run a node with additional memory by running the node's corda JAR from the command line with the following flag:

```
java -Xmx2048m -jar corda.jar
```

You can also specify that the node should be run with extra memory in the node's `node.conf` configuration file:

```
myLegalName="O=PartyA,L=London,C=GB"
...
jvmArgs=["-Xmx8G"]
```

Finally, you can specify that the node should be run with extra memory in the `deployNodes` task:

```
task deployNodes(type: net.corda.plugins.Cordform, dependsOn: ['jar']) {
    directory "./build/nodes"
    node {
        name "O=Node,L=London,C=GB"
        ...
        extraConfig = [
            jvmArgs : [ "-Xmx1g"]
        ]
    }
}
```

See https://docs.corda.net/running-a-node.html#starting-an-individual-corda-node.

Comment: We have tried to use this `extraConfig = [ jvmArgs : [ "-Xmx1g" ] ]` in the `build.gradle`, and the node generation seems to work fine. But when I try to start the node, I receive the following error: `[ERROR] 13:01:06-0200 [main] internal.Node.run - Unknown configuration keys: [jvmArgs]`. In `node.conf`, the snippet is `jvmArgs=[
    "-Xms2G",
    "-Xmx8G"
]`.
What is the correct approach to get this node memory configuration working ?

Comment: It works for me. If in `deployNodes` I add `extraConfig = [ jvmArgs: [ "-Xms2G", "-Xmx8G" ]]`, the `node.conf` gets `jvmArgs=["-Xms2G", "-Xmx8G"]` and the node runs successfully.

Comment: `Quicksilver:Test vfalcao$ java -jar corda.jar --version
Corda Enterprise Edition 3.1
Revision c9b23a4400923a5cfe88271ce2fedd75740eac40
Platform Version 3
Quicksilver:Test vfalcao$ java -jar corda.jar
[ERROR] 13:01:06-0200 [main] internal.Node.run - Unknown configuration keys: [jvmArgs].
` -- I still got the error. Any pointers for get us in the right direction ?

Answer (score 1):

Adding `extraConfig` in Gradle's `Cordform` task worked for me with Corda Enterprise 4.2:

```
task deployNodes(type: net.corda.plugins.Cordform) {
    nodeDefaults {
        // ...
        extraConfig = [ custom: [jvmArgs: [ "-Xms8G", "-Xmx8G", "-XX:+UseG1GC" ]] ]
    }
    // ...
}
```

The resulting node.conf fragment is:

```
custom {
    jvmArgs=[
        "-Xms8G",
        "-Xmx8G",
        "-XX:+UseG1GC"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding following block in "task deployNodes" section worked for me -

> extraConfig = [
>               jvmArgs : [ "-Xmx1g"]
>           ]